# What apps have nifty maven poms and are good as examples of maven capabilites

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm looking for applications that have "rich" maven pom(s) and can show lot of maven capabilities(plugins). These applications are needed as showcase examples - how fast and how many this can be done with maven and appropriate set of plugins.

There are no constraint to technology or application type - it must be opensorce and easy to build. I'm not looking for best one but thouse which are worth to look and build. In yours examples please add comments, what cool features that projects's maven build offer.

Obviously, these poms will be also inspiration to improve my own/others projects poms.

I personally found that [Richfaces Photo Album Example](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/branches/community/3.3.X/examples/photoalbum) was worth to look. In this project (Java EE webapp) there are functional test with cargo and selenium, use of scm plugin (export form svn), generation and deployment of ear to jboss server.

---

Why not examples from maven books? The should be real projects to convince to maven boss/stakeholders/workmates.

Why I can't get first one project build by maven? Because usually projects (not all) are only built by maven, and contain no additional reports or plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find [Maven's bootstrap build](http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-m2.html) funny: build Maven to build Maven. Note that it is possible to build Maven with Maven already installed but I'm not sure this build shows a wide features set usage.

From this point of view, [JBoss AS](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/trunk/) might already be a better example, but not the "best" (if this has a sense). Actually, I like [XWiki](http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/Building)'s build (Vincent Massol is working there). Or [Exo Platform](http://wiki.exoplatform.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/Building+from+sources)'s one (Arnaud Heritier is working there).

I'm pretty sure XWiki and Exo Platform are good examples as their respective build manager have a deep knowledge of Maven (as more or less active maven committers): these build are full of best practices, show the right way to do things, have a clean modules organization, etc. In other words, they are representative of the "state of the art" with Maven.

Comment: Lots of frameworks do that nowadays actually, for example JUnit validates itself by using JUnit :)

Comment: +1 for recursion example :). The last time I built Maven from sources was over 2 year ago. Maybe it's time to checkout sources and run the build and see what have changed. But build Maven Project seems to be 'heavy' for regular maven users and takes long time (the first one).

Comment: Thanks. I remember Vincent as one of first few Maven 2 gurus/commiters and author of first Maven book and Cargo plugin.

Comment: I had the pleasure to work with him during 2 years, a great experience (we were then using maven 1.0-b8).