# maven open source project

Tags: maven-2, open-source, cvs

Please, I want to test CVS and Maven tools within an existing project so:

is there any open source project that I can check out from its "CVS" and build it with "Maven"?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fairly large project to try out, you can take a look at Shindig:

http://incubator.apache.org/shindig/

The instructions for building it with maven and running from within eclipse are here:

http://incubator.apache.org/shindig/developers/java/build.html

Comment: New URL for build instructions: http://shindig.apache.org/documentation_building_java.html

Answer (score 1):

PortletBridge would be a good one.

- website: http://www.portletbridge.org
- source checkout info:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/portletbridge/develop

Be sure to specify portletbridge-ng as the module.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most of open source java project use Maven, but I think SVN is more popular. If you are looking for other examples (might be svn) look at mz previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556823/what-apps-have-nifty-maven-poms-and-are-good-as-examples-of-maven-capabilites)

To find test project go to SourceForge.net, search for *java* projects, choose project and then open *Develop* tab like in this [Hibernate example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/develop). There is high probability that project you choose is build by Maven.